# Python 2.6.6 and hive connectivity issue?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have a VM with default Python version 2.6.6 and hive 1.2. I have installed pyhs2 successfully. But when I run the python script I get the error below.

```
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost', port=10000, authMechanism="PLAIN", user='hive', password='hive', database='xxxx') as conn:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyhs2/__init__.py", line 7, in connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyhs2/connections.py", line 46, in __init__
transport.open()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 55, in open
self._trans.open()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 101, in open
message=message)
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:10000
```

In my hive-site.xml I have the below configuration.

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
  <value>NONE</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>
```

When I use the below script:

```
with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost', port=10000, authMechanism="NONE", user='hive', password='hive', database='xxxx') as conn:
```

I get the error below:

```
NotImplementedError: authMechanism is either not supported or not implemented.
```

Please help!

Please note that client will not allow me to upgrade the python version or to change the authentication mechanism in Hive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) check this https://github.com/BradRuderman/pyhs2/blob/master/pyhs2/connections.py

```
authMechanisms = set(['NOSASL', 'PLAIN', 'KERBEROS', 'LDAP'])
```

authMechanisms should be one of these

2) Error on `thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:10000`
Type `netstat -a -n | grep 10000` and check service is listening on port 10000